# C# - Run an executable inside windows form

Tags: c#, exe

Is it possible to run an executable inside a windows form in C#? For example use `cmd.exe` in a frame? I'd like to do this with PuTTY like SuperPuTTY does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, as long as the program you want to control works from the command line (stdin / stdout).

Start the process and redirect the Standard Out, Standard In, and Standard Error to your application, so you can display the info on your form.

The following link contains some sample code on how to start and redirect:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx